Ubuntu 24.04 hplip from distro has python failure
On a working Ubuntu 24.04 system connected on a USB cable to a HP printer, I used apt to install hplip and hplip-gui from the standard Ubuntu distro.  There were no diagnostic messages -- everything seemed to work.  I then tried to setup the printer using the hplip-gui, but the application never allowed me to complete.  I then opened a terminal application and invoked hp-setup.  The GUI appeared and again hung; however, the terminal had diagnostic messages during execution of hp-setup that I have copied below.  There appear to be missing python dependencies that apt (actually, apt-get) does not force to be installed with the packages.  Any help greatly would be appreciated.  To the monitors/censors of this list:  truncating the diagnostic output may eliminate a clue as to how to correct the failure.

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.23.12)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Searching... (bus=usb, search=(None), desc=0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog.py", line 1394, in NextButton_clicked
    self.showAddPrinterPage()
  File "/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog.py", line 708, in showAddPrinterPage
    self.findPrinterPPD()
  File "/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog.py", line 797, in findPrinterPPD
    self.print_ppd = cups.getPPDFile2(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/share/hplip/prnt/cups.py", line 539, in getPPDFile2
    family_class=getFamilyClassName(model)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/share/hplip/prnt/cups.py", line 181, in getFamilyClassName
    family_type= dict[m]['family-class']
                 ~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'family-class'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 228, in partial_apport_excepthook
    return apport_excepthook(binary, exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 123, in apport_excepthook
    report.add_package_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 442, in add_package_info
    package = apport.fileutils.find_file_package(self["ExecutablePath"])
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 175, in find_file_package
    return packaging.get_file_package(file)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl/apt_dpkg.py", line 631, in get_file_package
    dpkg = subprocess.run(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 548, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 1955, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'dpkg-divert'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog.py", line 1394, in NextButton_clicked
    self.showAddPrinterPage()
  File "/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog.py", line 708, in showAddPrinterPage
    self.findPrinterPPD()
  File "/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog.py", line 797, in findPrinterPPD
    self.print_ppd = cups.getPPDFile2(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/share/hplip/prnt/cups.py", line 539, in getPPDFile2
    family_class=getFamilyClassName(model)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/share/hplip/prnt/cups.py", line 181, in getFamilyClassName
    family_type= dict[m]['family-class']
                 ~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'family-class'```
        


There are two issues.  One is that key error, but the second one is it's trying to all dpkg probably to install packaging, etc. and can't.  Did you run hp-setup as root or with sudo or did you just run hp-setup as your user?

I tried both.  However, the diagnostics resulted from running it in the user account.   If I do try it again with a sudo hp-setup what is one to do about the key error?

If you run as sudo and get a key error still then you need to file a bug against hplip
